# Twilio MMS with long text message produces undesirable text wrapping

Tags: twilio, mms

If it's just a regular sms the message's output is in correct, normal top-down order. But when you throw, lets say, a video into the mix Twilio takes the second part of the text message and puts in on top of the video which is already on top of the first part of the text message! Bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Twilio MMS long text message output]

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  I'd suggest dropping a line to our awesome support team with a few of the message SID's that represent messages with this behavior.  https://www.twilio.com/help/contact They have the tools to dig into whats exactly going on with these messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our support team, there is no means to guarantee delivery order in these cases. Some carriers do not support concatenation of messages and may be what you're experiencing here.

A workaround might be to [send the initial MMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) with the image, then in your application logic to set a short delay of a few seconds or so to then send out the SMS contents. To ensure proper concatenation, perform character counting in app space and intelligently split the messages and send in order using the same time delay request approach.

I hope this helps!